# Does someone need to leave a comment on a question or answer when voting it down?

Tags: discussion, voting, comments

One occasionally encounters comments to the effect of "Why the downvote? It is not useful to downvote without commenting."

Are users who vote down a question or answer expected or required to comment explaining their reasons for their vote?

Comment: Hmm - are you intending to stake out new ground compared to this post? http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1693

Comment: 'Doh. How did I not find that in my search?!?

Comment: I've got several of these on the main meta - search, search, ask - then see the related list and get duped again.